# What is the proper method for including a class in Wordpress plugin

Tags: php, class, plugins, wordpress

Forgive me, but I cannot seem to find this seemingly simply answer anywhere.

I have one class (for interacting with MailChimp API) which I am including in my Wordpress plugin. The problem is, using `include` inside an action hook isn't working.

For example:

```
function load_class() {
    include( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'includes/MailChimp.class.php');
    }
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'load_class');
```

doesn't work.

Can someone tell me (with an example) how I **should** include a php class from within a Wordpress plugin?

**EDIT:** Corrected class name in add_action() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said

> I have one class (for interacting with MailChimp API) which I am
>   including in my Wordpress plugin.

Why, you are using a `hook` here ? You can directly include this class in your working plugin. just, include `MailChimp.class.php` from within your plugin file, as normally you do in `php`. Also, check the another answer, you have made another mistake and it'is

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'load_mailchimp_class');
```

should be

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'load_class');
```

but not useful here. you don't need to use this. You asked for an example, include the `class` from your `plugin.php` file before you use it, like

```
include( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'includes/MailChimp.class.php');
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I had the function correct in my code but mis-typed it here. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

Your `add_action()` should read `add_action('plugins_loaded', 'load_class');`.

[Read more on Codex.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action)